# AngularJS - on submit, change specific dom attributes

Tags: angularjs

Ok, so this might sound like  validation, but it is more a courtesy notification function.

The problem: I have a ng-repeat that displays person data in the form of name surname in input boxes to allow the user to edit the names and/or surnames.
I would like to notify the user on submit that they are going to submit data where there are surnames with no names. Currently I can easily find the nameless surnames, but as soon as I apply the css it gets applied to all the elements. How to only apply it to the nameless objects?
Also, should this rather be done via a directive?

I have tried quite allot of things already, at the moment the simplest solution is shown below.

Note: This example is for a proof of concept for a more complex data structure, hence the silly data.

Here is the code:

**HTML:**

```
<body ng-app="ap" ng-controller="con">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>name</td>
        <td>surname</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="person in persons">
        <td>
            <input type='text'
            ng-class="empty"
            ng-model="person.name"
            value="{{ person.name }}"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='text'
            ng-model="person.surname"
            value="{{ person.surname }}"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button ng-click="submit()">Change Class</button>
```

**The Controller:**

```
    var app = angular.module("ap",[]);

    app.controller("con",function($scope){

    $scope.persons = [
        {name: '', surname: 'Peters'},
        {name: 'Sue', surname: 'Anne'},
        {name: 'Jack', surname: 'Daniels'},
        {name: '', surname: ''},
        {name: '', surname: 'Bar'},
        {name: '', surname: 'Other'},
    ];

    $scope.empty = "normal";

    $scope.submit = function(){
        for(var i = 0; i < $scope.persons.length; i++) {
            if($scope.persons[i].name === '') {
                    $scope.empty = "empty";
            }
        }
    };
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.empty{
border-style: solid;
border-color: rgba(255, 135, 66, 0.75);
background-color: rgba(252, 102, 2, 0.54);
}

.normal{
    color: black;
}
```

Here is a link to the fiddle: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/staalburger/h80ky4fs/6/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be to add the empty class property to each person object.

**[FORKED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/0jp5v8pq/2/)**

*JAVASCRIPT*

```
$scope.submit = function(){
    var persons = $scope.persons, person;
    for(var i = 0; i < persons.length; i++) {
        var person = persons[i];
        person.empty = person.name? '': 'empty';
    }
};
```

*HTML*

```
    <tr ng-repeat="person in persons">
        <td>
            <input type='text'
            ng-class="person.empty"
            ng-model="person.name"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='text'
            ng-model="person.surname"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Note: You don't need to explicitly declare the `value` attribute since the `ng-model` directive will do it for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, works great, the answer by @Simon H is a bit more suited to the implementation I need. Thank you also for pointing out the the redundant value statement.

Comment: I have edited my answer somehow, some problems with the fiddle wherein the user submits the second time and inputs that have content still retains the `empty` class.

Comment: Just to note, I had to implement pagination with the problem I had and your answer did the job better, the ng-repeat had a filter applied, so the $index became useless. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I updated your fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/h80ky4fs/8/ - to make $scope.empty an array, and modified the html likewise

```
$scope.submit = function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.persons.length; i++) {
        if($scope.persons[i].name === '') {
                $scope.empty[i] = "empty";
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you make $scope.empty an array? Is it so that each item in the repeat matches to an index and value in the 'empty' array?

Comment: Each ngRepeat creates a small local scope, so you need an array of values to control them.  In your code, you wanted $scope.empty to control x different things simultaneously and what you got was that *all* the elements were either highlighted or not highlighted.  If you are happy with this approach, please mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Great, thanks allot. Makes sense to me. Both answers work, but I like your approach more, it makes it easier to remove the class with a watcher later on.